# How to bind null value in anchor tag and null element in v-for in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm having a table something like this:

[image: Data table]

I'm facing two difficulties here:

1. I'm having a document link, which in create form is not mandatory field, so the data which comes through response sometimes have null value which throws error and makes table data disappear. I'm trying to implement something like this

   `<td class="text-center">
       <a :href="item.document.link" target="_blank">
           <i class="fa fa-eye text-navy"></i>
       </a>
   </td>`

This throws error:

> [Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'link' of null"

2. I'm having two columns for target price old and revised, during the creation of the data set only one target price is being inserted and the response which sends the data is inside one variable something like this:

   `"target_prices":
       [
           {"id":3,"research_id":16,"price":"90"}
           {"id":4,"research_id":16,"price":"91"}
       ]`

So in this case there might be only one data inside `target_price` as:

```
"target_prices":
[
    {"id":3,"research_id":16,"price":"90"}
]
```

this makes table shift as, you can see in the image the table is being shifted, I'm using a simple `v-for` loop to show the values.

```
<td class="text-center" v-for="target in item.target_prices">{{ target.price }}</td>
```

I simply want to display null or NA under `Old` if only one value is available. and show the difference of both under change in TP
Help me out in this. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your first issue, you can specify a `v-if` on the `<a>` tag to only render it if the `item.document` exits:

```
<td class="text-center">
  <a v-if="item.document" :href="item.document.link" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-eye text-navy"></i>
  </a>
</td>
```

---

For your second issue, you can check the length of the array in a `<template>` tag and display a different template if there is only one element in the `item.target_prices` array via `v-if` and `v-else`:

```
<template v-if="item.target_prices.length === 1"> 
  <td class="text-center"> N/A </td>      
  <td class="text-center">{{ item.target_prices[0].price }}</td>
</template>
<template v-else>
  <td class="text-center" v-for="target in item.target_prices">
    {{ target.price }}
  </td>
<template>
```

Comment: I guess during first v-if in target price will be `item.target_prices[0].price` and how to get the difference of these two?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking